# Sencha Touch 2: How can I add Google+ Login?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, google-plus, google-signin, sencha-touch-2.3

I would like to add a Google+ Login to my Sencha Touch 2 webapplication, according to https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/?hl=de#using_the_client-side_flow.

I have added the google script into the app.json (defined as remote script) and it gets loaded. 
I created a Container with the html stuff (described by google):

```
Ext.define('Bubbles.view.LoginView', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
id: 'loginView',
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    html: '<span id=\"signinButton\">'
        +   '<span class="g-signin" data-callback="signinCallback" data-clientid="CLIENT_ID" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"></span>'
        + '</span>',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
}});
```

But the screen stays empty, no login button :-(

However, removing this html section above and adding it directly into index.html works. Unfortunately, this is a very bad practice...

Any ideas how to do it properly with Sencha Touch 2?

Comment: try to set the html in initialize listener or method.  `config : { listeners : { initialize : function () { this.setHtml(<<html>>); } }`

Comment: Does unfortunately not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not working because the `.g-signin` element is getting added to the dom after after Google tries to render the button. Take a look at [adding the sign-in button to your page with JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript). Especially step four where `gapi.signin.render('myButton', additionalParams);` is used to render the button.

Comment: Thanks, adding the button manually according to your link works like a charm!